# JQuery Ajax not returnig utf-8 characters

Tags: jquery

i have ajax function that looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        action: 'get_data',
        article_id: some_var
    },
    url: 'http://www.example/test.php',
    success: function(msg) {
    jQuery('#some_div').html(msg);
    }
});
```

In test.php i have mysql query that gets row from base, with id that is equal to article_id. It works good. BUT i have some serbian language characters in database, and when ajax returns that characters, they look like this: "Ž" is "�", and "Š" is "?".
Data is corectly stored in mysql (utf8 connections, colations and all other stufs), html page encoding is utf8... I am missing something, i dont know what...

Comment: What is the browsers character encoding?

Comment: It is same with UTF-8 or some other encoding set in browser.

Comment: If you hit test.php?article_id=x do you get the correct UTF-8 output?

Comment: Good idea, i tried with GET, directly to test.php, but no, output is still wrong. What is that mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, i add after connection to base: mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION='utf8_general_ci'"); . I thought that this is important only when inserting data to base

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the datatype to the ajax query:

```
dataType: 'html'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set character encoding in html in tag `meta` if it is not there.
2. Use something like `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` function on server side.

Comment: 1. Already set 2. This makes probleamtic characters to dissapear.